# Cannot execute binary file: Exec format error (code 126)

Tags: git-husky

Here are the error messages when I commit:

> .husky/../npmw: line 30: .husky/../target/node/node: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
> Using node installed locally
> .husky/../npmw: line 40: .husky/../target/node/node: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
> Using npm installed locally
> .husky/../npmw: line 41: .husky/../target/node/node: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
> husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 126 (error)

Not sure if it's related to `.husky/precommit`

content as below:

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"


"$(dirname "$0")/../npmw" exec --no-install lint-staged
```

Originally,I use `git commit -m "xxx" --no-verify`, but now I'm not allowed to due to my supervisor.

I've tried npm install.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this error appeared on Windows and husky version 5.x, and I also encountered the same problem, and then I deleted ./husky/commit-MSG files, and after manually re-creation, I can submit it normally.

Comment: Hi, thank you. At first, it still gave me the same error. But I realized it could be my node.exe not working, so I also deleted node.exe and copy a new one and replace it. Now with your solution and this, it works. Thank you!

Comment: The same for me I deleted commit-msg and then manually created that file, and then it worked.